# Finding a pixel and tracking its color change

Tags: autohotkey

There is a script that for some reason does not work.
I explain the situation: There is a mini game in which there are green rings and they change their position (not random) every time the white ring stops using the space bar on them.
I wrote a little script to find the green color, but for some reason it does not work.

```
 F5::
    loop {
        PixelGetColor, color1, 957, 672, RGB
        PixelGetColor, color2, 957, 672, RGB
        if(color1 != 0x10A04B){ 
            Sleep, 80
        } else {
            Soundbeep
            Sleep, 80
        }
        if(color2 != 0xFDFFFE){ 
            Sleep, 80
        } else {
            Send, {space}
        }
    }
return
```

To help you fully understand the mini game, I'm sending you a link to the video: https://youtu.be/b4y1aiQNea4

Please help me understand the implementation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a timer instead of the loop
2. Try using Alt or Slow mode
3. For finding the green ring coordinates try using PixelSearch, then you will be able to specify variation of the color (it's necessary due to it being partially transparent)

Comment: `#SingleInstance,Force
CoordMode Mouse
CoordMode Pixel

ColorWhite = 0xffffff
ColorGreen = 0x0e9949
F4::
Loop
{
  PixelSearch X, Y, 712, 571, 1358, 1079, ColorGreen, 10, Fast RGB
  if (ErrorLevel = 0)
  {
  SoundBee
  }
 }   `
How can I make it so that when the green color changes to white (0xffffffffff), then {space} is pressed?

I tried this: `if (GreenColor = 0xffffffff) 
{ 
Sand, {space} 
}`

But that doesn't work :(

The `PixelSearch X, Y, 712, 571, 1358, 1079, ColorGreen, 10, Fast RGB` function works fine. Great for finding green in any of the circles.

Answer (score 0):

```
colorchange(x,y){
    PixelGetColor,color,x,y
        if (color=0xffffffffff){
        Return 1}Else{
        Return 0}
}

if colorchange(X,Y){
    Send,{Space}
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks, it works, but in the game the ring moves too fast, so the script does not have time to work. I tried reproducing the situation in photoshop and your suggestion works!!! Miracle.